# Setting up .net project in IIS locally with URL 'application.local'

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to set up a .NET application locally to run with a different alias to 'localhost'. The application has a successful connection to the database and runs correctly when running as localhost.

In some of my projects, I am able to access the application on the browser by writing '.local' after the application name. For example, a project called toysandstuff can be accessed in the web browser with 'toysandstuff.local. instead of having to run it through Visual Studio and localhost.

I have this set up for some of my applications at work but i'm not sure how to configure IIS and Visual Studio to run the project as '.local' instead of using localhost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what actually you want? are you looking to configure IIS server on your PCso that you can run it via ip address or the name assigned without running Visual studio? please elaborate so that we can understand it better.

Comment: Name assigned without running visual studio. Say I access my toysnstuff website by typing localhost:5000 into the address bar, I want to achieve the same effect as localhost:5000 by typing toysnstuff.local

I also want Visual Studio to use toysnstuff.local when running debug mode in Visual Studio, rather than localhost:5000